# Import data from Excel into SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, database, excel

My question is not regarding how this is done, the application that I'm currently working on converts Excel to XML (using standard XSD), and then we have scripts to read data from XML and put it into database.

Why we need to generate XML, can't we directly import data from Excel to database? What is the benefit of this XML?

Answer (score 0):

Its Light weight and portable across any database, irrespective of the underlying os or type of DB structure we cab use it directly.

I don't know about your application or its purpose.
If you want to use webservice or RPC services the you can go by xml